# I want to evaluate a postgres database , can anyone guide me what all things i have to look into it as a Dba do

Tags: postgresql

it used to be a Postgres database but without any data, I should analyze the database efficiency

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

One tip:

You don't analyse **Databases**.
Left to their own devices, Databases are surprisingly efficient and well-behaved processes that *don't* chew up all the machine's memory or use up all the disk space.
For that to happen, they have to have tables, *with* data, in them, plus indexes, views, etc., and *queries* running against those tables.

You analyse **Workloads**.
The traffic going through the database, hitting all those tables, view, indexes, etc. will create their own, unique profile ...   and *that's* what you need to tune.

In my experience:

- You can spend several days tweaking server and DBMS settings and you *might* get 2 - 3 *percentage points* improvement.
- You can spend that same time looking at table structures, indexing, query structures, etc. and you might get 2 - 3 *Order of Magnitude* improvement.